# Writing a random variable as the sum of independent random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, independence, poisson-distribution

Let $X_i$ be independent random variables with $X_i \sim Po(1)$. We know (for instance by looking at characteristic functions) that then $\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i \sim Po(n)$. I am interested in the converse of that implication.
Let $Y \sim Po(n)$. Can we find independent random variables $Y_1, ..., Y_n$ with $Y_i \sim Po(1)$ such that  $\sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i=Y$?

Comment: This is a good question but I think one needs extra randomness (i.e., one cannot achieve this in any probability space).

Comment: in the distribution sense, of course, you already shown it. However in the stronger sense of random variables, probably not

Comment: @Masacroso This is possible in the stronger sense if further independent samplings (conditionally on $X$) is allowed. See my answer.

Comment: This is probably not going to be possible in general. You need to assume extra randomness. Specifically, you need to assume that alongside $Y$ there exists another random variable (uniform usually suffices) and then you can beak down the uniform random variable to create the $Y_k.$ @nejimban has provided a very nice picturesque construction.

Comment: @WilliamM, yes this is precisely what I was saying. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First sample $X\sim\text{Poisson}(n)$. Then toss a $n$-faced fair die $X$ times independently, letting $Y_k$ denote the total number of times face number $k\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ has showed up. It is clear that $$X=\sum_{k=1}^nY_k$$
whatever the random realization of $X$ may be.
Further, $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ are independent $\text{Poisson}(1)$ r.v. Indeed, for any $a_1,\ldots,a_n\in\Bbb Z_+$ we have, with $N:=a_1+\cdots+a_n$,
\begin{align*}
\Bbb P\Bigl(Y_1=a_1,\ldots,Y_n=a_n\Bigr)&=\Bbb P\Bigl(Y_1=a_1,\ldots,Y_n=a_n\:\Big|\: X=N\Bigr)\cdot\Bbb P(X=N)\\[.4em]
&=\binom{N}{a_1,\ldots,a_n}\left(\frac1n\right)^{\!N}\cdot{\mathrm e}^{-n}\frac{n^N}{N!}\\[.4em]
&=\left(\frac{\mathrm e^{-1}}{a_1!}\right)\cdots\left(\frac{\mathrm e^{-1}}{a_n!}\right)\\[.4em]
&=\Bbb P\Bigl(\text{Poisson}(1)=a_1\Bigr)\cdots\Bbb P\Bigl(\text{Poisson}(1)=a_n\Bigr).
\end{align*}

---

Formal construction of $(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)$. As stated in my earliest comment, we need a bit of extra independent randomness for this construction. So, suppose there exists a Uniform$(0,1)$ random variable $U$ independent of $X$. (If it does not exist, say we augment the probability space by taking its product with $((0,1),\mathcal B[0,1),\text{Leb})$.)

Then $(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n):=f(X,U)$ where $f\colon\Bbb Z_+\times(0,1)\to\mathbb(\Bbb Z_+)^n$ is the measurable map such that for any $y_1,\ldots,y_n\in\mathbb Z_+$, we have $(y_1,\ldots,y_n)=f(x,u)$ if, for all $1\le k\le n$, $y_k$ is the number of occurrences of digit $k$ in the first $x$ digits of $u$ when written in base $n$.

Comment: Note that "tossing $X$ times a die" is just a picturesque expression. What you are really doing is, on the event $X = s,$ you consider $s$ independent copies of $U$ a discrete uniform on $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ and define the $Y_k$ accordingly. How do you define $Y_k(\omega)$ so that $X(\omega) = \sum_k Y_k(\omega)$? This is what OP wants, equality $\omega$-by-$\omega$ (a.e.)

Comment: @nejimban ah!, you are right, I didn't read carefully. Anyway it will be better to clarify your construction

Comment: @WilliamM. It is picturesque just for sake of clarity. In more mathematical terms, if an independent Uniform$(0,1)$ random variable $U$ exists alongside $X$, I construct $(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)=f(X,U)$ where $(f(x,u))_k$ counts the number of times digit $k$ appears in the first $x$ digits of $u$ when written in base $n$. All we assume here is the existence of $U$.